# jquery : how to test for Ready when document is in a FRAME and it contains a large image with an image-map?

Tags: jquery, frameset, ready

I am encountering problems which I believe to be related to the document (inside a FRAME) not being quite ready to go, and would like to know what the best practices are for testing for "ready" using jQuery 1.3.2 -- the version required for a particular plug-in that I'm using.

Also, should the test be done in the document that sets up the frameset or in the document that gets loaded by the frameset?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just having to wait for the image to load, could you just use the image's `onload` event handler instead?

```
var imgMap = new Image();
....
imgMap.onload = function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that useful tip, though it won't always be an image I'm waiting for. Best practices with framesets seems hard to pin down.